# Generating random integers in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, random, tensorflow-probability

I would like to generate random integers in TensorFlow but I don't which command I should use. In particular, I would like to generate from a uniform random variable which takes values in {1, 2, 3, 4}. I have tried to look among the distributions included in `tensorflow_probability` but I didn't find it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For simple integers from uniform distribution you could use [tf.random.uniform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/uniform).
In order to get the specified range and integers you should specify the `minval`, `maxval` and `dtype` parameters. So in your case:

For Tensorflow 2.0 and above:

```py
print(tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=1, maxval=5, dtype=tf.int32)
```

For Tensorflow 1.15 and below:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    random_int = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=1, maxval=5, dtype=tf.int32)
    print(sess.run(random_int))
```

Note that the actual maximum value will be `maxval-1`.